# Checking asimptotic stability of a critic point.

Tags: stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I've studied all the critical points of the following system using Hartman's Theorem, but for the (1,0) doesn`t apply because it's not hyperbolic. So I would like to find a strict Lyapunov function to determine the asimptotical stability.

$$\begin{cases}\frac{d}{dt}x=x(1-x+y)\\
\frac{d}{dt}y=y(1-x-y)\end{cases}$$

$$ Let\,\, U_{(1,0)}\subset R^{2}\,\,be\,\, a\,\, neighbourhood\,\, of\,\, the\,\, point\,\, (1,0) \\$$
I've tried $$V(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}-1$$ Satisfies $$V(1,0)=0$$
$$V(x,y)>0,\,\,\forall(x,y)\in R^{2}\setminus U(1,0)$$
but I have problems to determine if $$V'(x,y)<0,\,\,\forall(x,y)\in U$$

Note: The point (1,0) can't be a centre because it lies on the invariant line y=0.

Comment: Did you mean to write $V(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2$? The function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ is *not* positive away from $(1,0)$ (for example, $V(x,0)<0$ for $-1<x<1$).

Comment: And the condition “$\forall (x,y) \in R^2 \setminus U(1,0)$” is also not the correct one for Lyapunov's theorem.

Comment: Also, did you try simply sketching the phase portrait (using the nullclines, etc.)? Because if you do, it should become pretty clear why your strategy is doomed... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bx%281-x%2By%29%2Cy%281-x-y%29%7D

Comment: Thanks Hans, i've sketched the phase portrait and I already knew how the vector field flows, but i want to proof it mathematicaly without sketching, using something stronger than the Theorem of continuty of solutions by a given initial conditions.

Comment: Well, if you've already realized that the equilibrium is **unstable**, why are you looking for a positive definite Lyapunov function with $V'<0$? That's what you would use to prove that it's **stable**.